# , double click on edit text then datepicker dialogue show. How to show it on single click

Tags: android

```
editdate.setOnClickListener( new View.`OnClickListener`() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
               int mYear = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
               int mMonth = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               int mDay = mcurrentDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
               DatePickerDialog mDatePicker;
               mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(CreatNotes.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                   public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    /*      Your code   to get date and time    */
                   //,    selectedmonth = selectedmonth + 1;
                      editdate.setText("" + selectedday + "/" + selectedmonth + "/" + selectedyear);
                   }
               }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
             //  mDatePicker.setTitle("Select Date");
               mDatePicker.show();

           }
       } );``
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this,

```
editdate.setFocusable(false);
editdate.setCursorVisible(false);
editdate.setKeyListener(null);
```

Comment: is this helpful ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

to you `edittext` xml code

Comment: yes sir its helping plz tell how i insert time in sb table using timepicker dialouge

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:focusable="false"` to your `EditText`.